# Memory management when adding a resized UIImage to a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitableview, uiimage

I have images cached and I want to resize them and display them in a tableview. Here's the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://huntify.com%@",[[hunts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] iconURL]]];
UIImage *logo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:url]];
logo = [logo imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0)];    
[[cell imageView] setImage:logo];
```

This works fine but I wonder how I should release the UIImage. I suspect that releasing the "logo" after setting the image-property to the UIImageView is wrong because of the imageScaledToSize-method. Should I assign a new UIImage when resizing and release the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a big memory leak here. By assigning another value to `logo` in `logo = [logo imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0)];`, you lose the reference to the original image you would need to release. So yes, you should use a new variable to store the result of `imageScaledToSize:` and then release the original `logo`.

Comment: Ok, as I suspected then... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Do this-

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://huntify.com%@",[[hunts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] iconURL]]];
UIImage *logo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:url]];
UIImage *resizedLogo = [logo imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0)];    
[[cell imageView] setImage:resizedLogo];
[logo release];
```

Comment: I never allocate the resizedLogo - should I really release it?

Comment: sorry, I ninja-edited the post once I saw it- you're right, the above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you are only releasing owenership of an object when you `[logo release]`, you are not dealloc'ing it.